# Node.js - HTTP Keep-Alive and thread pool

Tags: node.js

I have a few questions that I hope you can help with.

Node.js use single threaded event loop and there is a thread pool that consist of **4** threads by default.

Let say i'm using Node.js as a web server and **Keep-alive** is enabled and is set to be idle up to 2 seconds before closing the connection.

if there is **8** unique clients trying to visit my website page, will only **4** be able to see the page until one of clients in the threads close the connection?

If not can you please explain why?

Answer (score 1):

Answer is no - one thread can serve many clients.

**TLDR;** It's because Node.js is using asynchronous I/O

Under the hood Node.js uses two technologies - libuv and v8

- **v8** is Javascript engine used by Google Chrome and other browsers (not interesting for us now).
- **libuv** is a library that provides the event loop and asynchronous I/O capabilities

**What is the event loop?**

Generally speaking it's a loop that's polling or querying some (usually external) source of events and a callback for each event that is executed when event is received. Something like this:

```
while (running) {
  event = get_event();
  callback = get_callback(event)
  callback();
}
```

If we do `fs.read()`, `socket.write()`, `setTimeout()`...

Under the hood this is going to 'schedule' events with callbacks that are about to be completed (using the callbacks) in future - but the code is not going to wait for each individual one, instead only the first event will be waited for (no matter which one completes first).

So `get_event` will return first event that completes.

**What is asynchronous I/O?**

For example reading from a file is usually so called blocking operation - meaning we ask x bytes from a file and we are going to block execution until OS to gives us the bytes. This is synchronous I/O.

Using asynchronous I/O it's possible to ask OS to give us the bytes and **not block so we can do something else**. When the bytes are ready we will get notified by event loop and process them - so called non-blocking operation.

Node is doing exactly that - **it's using mostly non-blocking operations to achieve concurrency on a single thread**. Manipulating files and using network can be done using OS's asynchronous I/O.

It's extremely useful because I/O operations usually make majority of execution time so our code instead of waiting is doing something useful - like handling connection from 8th or 100th client.